# Why for deserialization of object of type 'Type' it is need an described type itself?

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization

I have a app with plugins, which are loaded dynamically. I keep types from those assemblies in an array of Type objects. Then, when app is closing, it saves this array into a file by serialization. When app is starting It load this file and try to deserialize It an error occurs because assemblies containing classes described in those types, are unavailable. I can't understand why It happens: a type 'Type' is in a mscorlib or something like this. Does object type has reference to type which It describe?

Comment: Deserialization creates a new object.  Which requires calling the object constructor.  Which is stored in one of those assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [`Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly.aspx) property of the type `Type`. That returns a reference to the assembly containing the type. In order to get that reference, the assembly has to be loaded (possibly "for reflection only"). Likewise you can ask a type for all its methods, etc - how would you expect that to work without the assembly being present?

I suppose a `Type` *could* be serialized in such a way that all the property values are only populated as and when they're required, so you *could* have a `Type` object which referred to a type in a missing assembly... but it would be pretty odd.

Perhaps you should just keep hold of the fully-qualified type *name* instead of the `Type` itself, if that's all you want to be able to rely on?

Comment: Hm. May I ask another question in such case: Will property AssemblyQualifiedName of type 'Type' always be unique? May It be confused with types from other assemblies or same assembly but new version?

Comment: @Praetor12: Well the AssemblyQualifiedName *includes* the assembly name, hence "assembly-qualified". Likewise it includes the namespace. Now you could *potentially* have two assemblies with the same name (if they're not strongly typed), although I'm not sure how you'd load them into the same AppDomain. In the vast majority of cases, AssemblyQualifiedName should be enough.

Comment: I just need to be sure that types will not be confused with each other. And, possible, there will be several types from assemblies differing only by their versions.

Comment: @Praetor12: If they're strongly-named assemblies, I believe that should be okay. If you're relying on an assembly version number but *without* strong naming, that may well *not* be good enough. I suggest you try it and see what's in the assembly-qualified name in each case.